# How do I get a remote time stamp in Inno Setup

Tags: timestamp, inno-setup, remote-server

I want to implement a demo of a software which is only usable for i.e. 30 days (typical shareware scenario). Therefore the program needs to remember when it was installed, but because the local time can be manipulated I want to save "reliable" information from a remote machine.

Is there any possibility to get a time stamp from a remote machine so that I can save it to the registry (using Inno Setup)?

I know that everything which gets saved locally can me manipulated and so can the remote time stamp. What would be another good method to achieve the goal?

thanks

Comment: It depends what you can publish on that remote machine. On that remote machine, do you have a web server, NTP server or... ?

Comment: At the moment there is no such (private) remote machine. My idea was to use a public one. Are there any reliable services to choose from?

Comment: I thought you are going to get timestamp from your own remote machine. Well, if you aim is to get timestamp from a certain public time server, a client able to work with NTP protocol would be the most precise you can get. Now looking at your update, you don't need to have such precision. It might be enough to call some of the web services returning timestamps. But for your aim I would call a service on your side and your side would tell if the program can start or not depending on how long the user has it installed. That's what user can't manipulate without cracking your application.